# How to convert this value to a valid date?

Tags: delphi, date, format

I catch the value of `Firstlogin` field from a table (from IBSng Database). i know that it is a `Date` but i don't know how can i convert it into a valid date .

The value of the field is : **`1304077351`**

how to convert it to a valid date format ?

Comment: What language and platform?  `Firstlogin` may well identify the language to those who know it, but means nothing to the rest of us.  Please edit the question to add the language to the tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it ! Thank you Anders

```
function UnixToDateTime(USec: Longint): TDateTime;
const
  // Sets UnixStartDate to TDateTime of 01/01/1970
  UnixStartDate: TDateTime = 25569.0;
begin
  Result := (USec / 86400) + UnixStartDate;
end;
```

Comment: You can select your own post as the answer.

Comment: The RTL has its own `UnixToDateTime()` function, in the `DateUtils` unit: `function UnixToDateTime(const AValue: Int64): TDateTime;` Note that the returned `TDateTime` is in UTC, so if you need it to be in local time instead, you have to adjust it manually using the local machine's timezone information.

Answer (score 10):

That is the [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for Fri, 29 Apr 2011 11:42:31 GMT.

**Edit**

According to [IBS](http://ibs.sourceforge.net/documentation.html#introduction), it uses postgresql as its backend database. You should be able to convert it using [to_timestamp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-formatting.html).